# HTTPS affecting multiple http sites on IIS7

Tags: iis-7

Can someone explain to me how I can fix this problem.

I have two sites hosted on the same IIS7 server.

Site 2 has SSL setup and can be found at https://www.site2.co.uk

Site 1 does not have ssl setup and is binded on http://www.site1.co.uk

Now if you go to https://www.site1.co.uk it throws this error on google:

**This is probably not the site that you are looking for!
You attempted to reach www.site1.co.uk, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as www.site2.co.uk**

I've tried using URl rewrite in webconfig file in site1 to stop it looking at port443 but had no luck :(.

Also tried editing applicationhost.config to include the following line but that did not work as well

Any help would be great on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a limitation in the original design of SSL, where the server must present a certificate without knowing what hostname the client wanted. So if you host two sites on the same IP address, the server has to pick one hostname to present to the client.

TLS SNI fixes this, but is not available in IIS 7 (available as of IIS 8):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Since many browsers also don't support SNI, it is common to run a single web server with multiple IP addresses, one IP address per site.